# app terminating suddenly without giving any exception in console in iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ios-simulator

i have a problem while building and running an iphone application.Im using xml parsing to get data and storing it in core data.From there im retrieving data to display in a table.As i did this,seems to be working becoz im able to display it in the table as well as in a console but the app was terminating suddenly without leaving any exception in console.I thought it may be becoz of not releasing any object and thouroghly checked it out.but everything is gud.Could u please let me know why this has been happening?

Comment: can you elaborate or post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the NSZombie. It will show you the exact problem in console.

Comment: Ya sure. following are the steps                                                                  1. In Groups & Files, Select           Executable                                                             2. Click info and select the arguments tab                                                                    3. There is option to set the Variable. clik on + button. Now write the NSZombieEnabled and in value field write YES.                                                                     That's all you need to do. Next time it will show the proper error message in Console.

Comment: Thankq so much i did it and i got  an msg like this -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5e71ec0
wat does this mean and my app is still in debugging mode.

Comment: That means you are releasing same string variable twice. string variable is already deallocated and you are trying to release it second time.

Comment: I just followed ur suggestion sir i found out the string and unreleased it.thats it.

Comment: - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller 
{
[self.tableView reloadData];
}

Comment: Have you used the [tableView reload]; option

Comment: i used this - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [appDelegate.CategoryArray removeAllObjects];
    [appDelegate getcategoryFromCoreData];
    [self.tblView reloadData];  [super viewWillAppear:animated]; 
}  i tried to use (NSFetchedResultsController  but got so many errors so u plz clearly tel me hw to use the (NSFetchedResultsController ?

Comment: After executing this method you will receive New data from Core Data  NSMutableArray *ArrayName = [appDelegate getcategoryFromCoreData]; something like this So whenever you come to this View you will get New collection of data in Array.

Comment: Hai Sir Gud Mrng - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller { [self.tableView reloadData]; } we used this code as it is but stil our prob persists wat to do sir plz help me out

Comment: You mean to say while creating table or during insert operation ?

Comment: What was the error message? See the console when your application terminate. It will help us to find the actual problem.

Comment: Are you using any other method ? I mean other than cellForRow.